# Finding Smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2&0\\-2&1&-1&-3\\3&0&3&3\\-4&-2&-6&-6\\-1&0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ transforms via Gaussian elimination to $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

(This is given in the exercise.) I have calculated a basis of the $1$-dimensional kernel of $A$, that is $v=(1,1,-1,0).$

Thus I get a basis $B=(e_1,e_2,e_4,v)$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Here $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector.

I also get a basis $B'=(Ae_1,Ae_2,Ae_4,e_2,e_5)$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Does this help to find invertible matrices $S,T$ such that $T^{-1}AS$ has Smith normal form?

Comment: Have you tried the algorithm in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form ? If so, where does it fail/give you problems?

Comment: No, because the second matrix is given to me so I don't know all the steps. As far as I see, $T=B'$ and $S=B$ works. Can you explain why that works or is it just random?